# How to show one toast at a time in onreceive() of broadcast receiver not all at once

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver, wifi, toast

I got a strange problem on restricting toast messages in OnReceive() of broadcast receiver

I have written code for displaying toast when wifi and bluetooth are enabled/disabled

but If  I enable/disable wifi, toast for bluetooth also appearing and viceversa i.e all 4 toast messages appearing one by one when I enable/disable bluetooth and wifi

What I want to do is I want to show one toast when wifi is off/on and also for bluetooth individually

like

```
 if WIFI is on  -  "wifi enabled"
 if WIFI is off -   "wifi disabled"
If bluetooth is on - "Bluetooth enabled"
If bluetooth is off - "Bluetooth disabled"
```

Only one toast at a time not all

How to get around this problem?

Here is my code

```
  public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver {
private WifiManager wifiManager;
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
      BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled()){  
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "WIFI  Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else {    
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "WIFI Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }  
    if(adapter.isEnabled()){

        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }else {    
        Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), " Bluetooth Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to display a single Toast at a time right ?

Comment: yes, a single toast at a time

Comment: ok got your requirement @Raghav, try my answer, you will get accurate result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Receiver is getting called whenever Wifi status is changed.And you showed Toast for Both Wifi and Bluetooth.So its showing Two toasts.Its not like that when Bluetooth is enabled or disabled Your wifi is None of enabled or disabled.Both wifi and bluetooth have enable or disable status.

To solve your problem you can try like

```
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(arg1.getAction().equals(WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION))  {  
            wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
            if(wifiManager.getWifiState()==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLED||wifiManager.getWifiState()==WifiManager.WIFI_STATE_ENABLING){  
                  Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "WIFI  Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else {    
                  Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "WIFI Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
    }else {  
            BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
            if(adapter.isEnabled()){
                  Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }else {    
                  Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), " Bluetooth Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }  
     }            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but where should I change the code? as I am new to android I dont know exactly what to do.

Comment: Thanks Rasel, but when I disable wifi its showing" wifi disabled" and when I enable wifi its showing "wifi disabled", "wifi enabled" its showing both toasts and the same in case of bluetooth also

Comment: @Rag its because its taking sometimes to enable and disable wifi.you can show wifi is enabled if isEnabling or isEnabled and disabled otherwise

Answer (score 0):

In your code you have two different **if** conditions, this is the only reason you are getting two Toast in display. look at my updated code here, it will solve your problem.

```
public class MyService extends BroadcastReceiver 
{
    private WifiManager wifiManager;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent arg1) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        BluetoothAdapter adapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        if(wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() )
        {  
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "WIFI  Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if (!wifiManager.isWifiEnabled() ) 
        {    
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "WIFI Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
        else if(adapter.isEnabled() )
        {
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth Enabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else if  (!adapter.isEnabled() )
        {    
            Toast.makeText(context.getApplicationContext(), " Bluetooth Disabled", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: Wifi is always enabled or disabled regardless of bluetooth.So he will never get a toast for bluetooth status.He has to test with the intent action "for what Action the receiver get fired"

Comment: Thanks, but when I disable wifi its showing" wifi disabled" and when I enable wifi its showing "wifi disabled", "wifi enabled" its showing both toasts and the same in case of bluetooth also. I tried both answers but  the result is same